# Comprobar si una celda de una tabla tiene un valor, y si lo tiene, borrar una opción de un select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yo tengo una tabla a la cual se le van sumando filas con los datos completados en un formulario, el cual se resetea y permite volver a cargar los datos para la próxima fila. Uno de los campos es un select, y una de esas opciones solamente puede seleccionarse una vez, por lo cual deseo que después de que sea seleccionada, y se escriba en la tabla, la opción desaparezca del select.
El problema que tengo es que, selecciones lo que selecciones, la opción se borra.
Las líneas que incluí para esto son:

```
if ($("#tablaPax td:contains(Jefe/a del Hogar')")){
        $("#Rol option[value='Jefe/a del Hogar']").remove();
}
```

Por el momento estoy tratando de hacerlo con JQuery, el cual recién estoy aprendiendo.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda